# Can't write unknown attribute using rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

Im' using `rails_admin` to save a `project` that has a `category` within. I didn't define `project_id` and `category_id` because I thought they should be created by rails. The problem I got were using the method `def category_id=(id)` defined in `project` model (see below). The error is:

```
can't write unknown attribute `project_id`
```

My models are:

**Category**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project, :inverse_of => :category

end
```

**Project**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :category, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :project

  def category_id
    self.category.try :id
  end
  def category_id=(id)
    self.category = Category.find_by_id(id)
  end

end
```

My **schema**:

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "text"
    t.string   "url"
    t.string   "key_feature"
    t.string   "image_1"
    t.string   "image_2"
    t.string   "image_3"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end
```

Comment: I think you are missing attr_accessible in your models.

Comment: I added `attr_accessible :id` in `project` model but now `rails_admin` cannot see the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution at the end was to manually add the `project_id` to `categories` table.

```
rails g migration add_project_id_to_categories project_id:integer
```

Thanks @Misha for you suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

How do you connect Projects to Categories?

Base on your schema **Projects** table has no category_id.

Neither you **Category** table has project_id

I would add category_id to Projects table.

```
rails g migration add_category_id_to_projects category_id:integer 
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: My approach was to connect them using the `has_one` option. One `project` only can have one `category`. I tried what you suggested but it didn't work. Remember that i'm using `rails_admin` gem.

Comment: You were almost right. I need to manually add the  `project_id` field in `categories` table. Thanks for the help.